# Can't find deployed app

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

I deployed my first meteor app on a digital-ocean droplet using mup. So it's there but I can't figure out what I still have to setup to actually view my app. So when I go to www.example.com I should see it but all I see is an apache page.

Comment: `example.com` is just domain given in some tutorial you referred as general example purpose and try using given IP to access it.

Comment: I'm using example.com as an example. Going to the IP has the same result. The apache page. Do I have to point to the app in my hosts file perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a Meteor app, you can specify the port for it to listen on using the `--port` argument. For it to be available from at you domain name specify port 80. Though if you have Apache listening on that port already it will fail to bind to it. Uninstall or stop Apache, and restart your Meteor app.

If you are using Apache to serve other content and can not stop it, you'll need to have your Meteor run on a different port with an Apache [ProxyPass.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) First enable `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http`

```
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

Then create a new VirtualHost for the Meteor app that proxies request to the port you have decided to have it listen on. It will look something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

[See this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) for all the details.

Comment: Okay so if I specify a different port for the app, how will that work? I need apache on that droplet for other things.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to set up a `ProxyPass` I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just a side note. I had to add my domain to the hosts file as well.